# How to display one item in my item details page from my item page using PHP/MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Okay So Here I'm trying to link a Item details page to a Item page, I have successfully done so however when I click on an item all the item details are showing up I would like to know how to Only Display one item on the item details page for the corresponding id. I know I'm missing some code (think its a GET or POST variable) to complete the link if anyone can help it will be much appreciated thanks alot

Heres my code

**item.php**

```
            <div class="rone">
            <?php
        $conn = new mysqli("xxx", "xxx", "xxx", "xxx");
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection Failed!" . $conn->connect_error);
        }
        ?>
            <?php
                $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM items');
                $stmt->execute();
                $result = $stmt->get_result();
                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()):
            ?>

            <div class="col-4">
                <a href="item-details.php?id=<?= $row['id'] ?>"><img src="<?= $row['itemimage'] ?>"></a>
                <h4"><?= $row['item_name'] ?></h4>
           </div>
           
            <?php endwhile; ?>                                                           
            </div>
```

**item-details.php**

```
            <div class="rone">
            <?php
        $conn = new mysqli("xxx", "xxx", "xxx", "xxx");
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection Failed!" . $conn->connect_error);
        }
        ?>
            <?php
                // UPDATE when this is done it does not work it gives the following error:: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function execute() on bool in C:\xampp\htdocs\assignment1\item-details.php:111 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in and the line 111 they referring to is this $stmt->execute(); ------ But if I do this //$id = $_GET['id'];
                //$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM items WHERE id = 1') the code will work just fine but it will only show item 1 regardless of which item I click. Hope this helps 
                //OLD
                //$id = $_GET['id'];
                //$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM items WHERE id = $id');
                //$stmt->execute();
                //$result = $stmt->get_result();
                //while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()):

               //UPDATED is this SQL Injection Proof?
                $id = $_GET['id'];
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE id = ?";
                $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql); 
                $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
                $stmt->execute();
                $result = $stmt->get_result();
                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()):


            ?>
            <div class="col-2">
                <img src="<?= $row['itemimage'] ?>" width="100%" id="ItemImg">                
            
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
                <h1><?= $row['item_name'] ?></h1>
            </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
```

the names of my rows are: id , itemimage, item_name and in time to come I will add other attributes
And the main table is items.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235532/discussion-on-question-by-flasat-how-to-display-one-item-in-my-item-details-page).

Answer (score -1):

I see $id ' ' );
Remove one of that ' to {$id}');

good now you have correct that and now you need do this

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE id = ?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql); 
$stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
$stmt->execute();
```

on bind_param there "i" what "i" mean? that mean numeric data for $id and if the $id is a string you should replace it with "s"

and don't forget close $stmt->close(); after finish using $stmt this is the best practice, because we don't know that did you use prepare stetment before or not in end that stetment and not end it.

Comment: My bad that was a typo and same issue 

Comment: Thanks for the help but it didn't help since everything is the same from [here](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli_examples/prepared_select) Which I've read way before you came ‍♂️ but humble to see you made the effort